# Does HAML have a way to shorten nested content that have only a single tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Currently I use something like this:

```
.row
  .col-md-6
    .row
      .col-md-12
        %h4
          %strong Title Section One
    .row
      .col-md-4
        %h4
          %strong Bold Content
      .col-md-4 Content 1
      .col-md-4 Content 2
      .col-md-4 Content 3
  .col-md-6
    .row
      .col-md-12
        %h4
          %strong Title Section Two
```

Is there a way for the "Bold Content" and the "Title Section" parts to be shorten down? Preferably down to a single line? Maybe something close to this:

```
      .col-md-4=%h4=%strong Bold Content
```

I know I can do use some CSS classes and/or IDs to achieve this, but I was wondering if HAML had a way to avoid making several indentation levels for a single line of content.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with HAML syntax, but HAML lets you embed HTML:

```
.col-md-4 <h4><strong>Bold Content</strong></h4>
```

Comment: I was hoping something was added by now. I've ended up switching to Slim.